Why does a power inductor make a loud noise when first turned on then decay to a calmer "hum" later?
I'm puzzled by this phenomenon. According to my lacking knowledge, a huge current draw at startup is exclusive to electric motors, where the lack of back EMF at zero speed causes big current draw. So such a thing should not happen in an inductor, at least it should happen once every cycle where the magnetic field in the core becomes zero, not at power up and then decay in a few seconds.
The video I have linked below has the exact same characteristic noise I'm currently experiencing in an inductor heater coil I'm working on:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VKLsWW4gym8
Below is a section view of mentioned induction heating device I am experiencing this noise on:

Parts 1, 2 and 3 are mating, and are mounted on to a motor shaft. They are rotating together around the coil(4) and the core(5). Coil and the core are secured to the motor chassis. Coil is operated at mains voltage and frequency. Coil is multiple layers of enamel copper wire wound in a single direction.
Any explanations or remedies regarding this phenomenon are welcome.

It's unbalanced flux at startup.
Consider the saturating inductor model:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This is adapted from INDSAT.ckt, available on Modeling | Seven Transistor Labs (links to my website).  Suffice it to say, everything right of RDC (winding DC resistance) constructs a nonlinear inductor out of simulation elements.

Notice the peak current is huge at start, decaying over time, as the flux settles down -- there is a DC offset in the startup condition, because one full half-wave hump of the sine wave is integrated whereas the inductor can only handle a bit over half of one (plus or minus, hence it runs fine steady-state).  This decays exponentially as the L/R time constant (where L is dependent).
Saturation is important, because most magnetic materials experience significant strain when saturated.  That's strain in the mechanical sense: the dimensions of the material deform under magnetic influence, an effect not due to mere magnetic forces but a property of the bulk material itself.  This effect is called magnetostriction.
The resulting strain transmits vibrations throughout the structure -- it shakes audibly -- hence the softer hum in normal operation, but the spikier waveform during startup giving a harsher buzzing sound.
Most transformers you'll interact with, have a modest "bump" sound on startup, as the time constant is short (as shown here); the L/R time constant generally grows with physical size, and there are other efficiency optimizations besides on transformers this big, which lengthen it further.  There might also be loose panels that produce a buzzing sound even from normal (smooth) running hum.
In the case of motors, they generate noise through Lorentz forces (literally, the torque they generate, which from a single-phase motor is also pulsating), as well as core saturation effects.  Particularly for the three-phase case, there's inevitably one section of the stator which ends up with "unlucky" phase at turn-on, which works itself out over time, contributing to noise; the other is simply that, when slip (difference between electrical and rotating frequencies) is large, the forces are large, startup current is at or near LRA (locked rotor amperes), and the windings and core are shaking it up.  Hence the BWWOOOoooommm sound of a big motor coming up to speed.
In the case of three-phase transformers (likely the video example), the same will apply, that one or two windings have "unlucky" phase and saturate, while the other(s) are fine.
The same Lorentz forces apply in transformers of course, we just generally don't overload them aside from during startup due to their own saturation.  Smaller transformers tend to have the windings well restrained (varnished or potted), so that magnetostriction is dominant.  But larger types may have open windings -- providing space for air or oil circulation, and enough distance for voltage isolation.  Open spans allow more motion of the windings; the motion will generally balance out across the unit, but some imbalance, or unlucky resonance, may result in overall vibration and audible noise.
To see the effect of phase, change the phase of V2 to 90° or what have you in the above simulation.  Line phase at switch closure is generally random (even if mechanical contacts are driven by mains frequency e.g. contactors with AC coils, the pull-in time isn't well synchronized -- the switching time has a large variance due to fumbling and friction), so you'll see a transformer sometimes do nothing at all, just click and it's on like nothing happened, and other times click and BWOOM big inrush current.
I don't know the load conditions in yours or the video's case, so it's likely some combination of these effects applies.

Thank you for the through explanation, I was able to finally understand what is inrush current. I found it to be impossible for AC operated inductors and now it makes sense. The device I'm working with is switched on with an SSR, the most basic type, so I guess it is a zero crossing turn-on type. On the internet it is suggested to use a PTC thermistor to limit the inrush current, but my device is turned on and off with 2-3 seconds of period, I guess a passive inrush limiter like PTC is not applicable here because there is no time to cool-down, am I right?

Yes, you might want to use a random-firing SSR and time it externally.

So, should I time the SSR firing to the voltage peak of AC mains waveform, where dV/dt is zero, to eliminate inrush current?

Somewhere around there.  It might be earlier or later depending on immediate current flow (transformer action: I guess as you're heating a steel part, there will be eddy currents involved here), and winding resistance (the steady-state magnetizing current isn't exactly 90° from applied voltage, but a little less due to resistance).  You can check waveforms with an oscilloscope and current probe and see what angle gives the least startup transient in your case. But probably 90/270 is close enough.

For the last 3 hours I'm looking for a ready made solution to achieve this, however, no temperature controllers have phase synchronization for their SSR drive output nor the power regulator SCR type switches have this functionality. There are some exotic peak-switching SSR's but they are unavaliable. I'm thinking of using a zero crossing SSR with a capacitor delay at it's output, connected to the input of a random fire SSR that drives the actual load. The first SSR will be solely used for zero crossing detection, which will be delayed by the capacitor. Do you think it would work?

Maybe. This goes well beyond the scope of the question asked, though. You might ask a new question about this. Mind that your options here are rather limited, if you're looking for a mostly-ready-made solution (can't ask for products); and an engineered solution is pretty apparent (just program an MCU to do it).

You are right, that is out of this current questions scope. I have one thing I don't understand about what you said before though, if I energize an inductor near AC peak voltage moment, since the voltage is coming from zero to AC peak voltage instantly, wouldn't the dV/dt be too high? Theoritically speaking such a fast voltage rise would induce even higher currents in the inductor, but appearently it doesn't. what am I missing?

A pure inductance is V = L dI/dt, you're thinking capacitor (I = C dV/dt). For a transformer with resistive load, current simply appears (or, the dI/dt is higher because inductance is a mix of magnetizing and leakage inductances).

This effect is common to all magnetic devices that have a magnetic core of some kind (transformers, motors, power inductors, solenoids, electromagnets, etc.).
It is caused by the magnetizing current (which is the principle component of inrush current) which is simply the current required to magnetize the magnetic core, much like a permanent magnet. This requires energy to do, and the current provides that energy.
This manifests as the inductor initially having much lower inductance than it normally would once the core has been magnetized. This is seen as the core having much lower permeability (which largely determines the inductance) briefly until it is magnetized (magnetic domains get aligned), increasing the permeability and thus the inductance.
As for the hum, this is not universal, but simply an artifact of mains power. It is cycling at a frequency of either 60Hz or 50Hz depending on the country, and that results in matching vibration due to various magnetic effects on the coil and core. Everything wiggles a little bit, to put it simply. And that wiggling is proportional to the current, so you're really just listening to the core becoming fully magnetized.
You would not hear anything if you applied DC however, simply because there is nothing to produce any vibration. The magnetizing current and inrush current effects are still there, but instead of something more gradual and magnetizing a bit more on each back and forth cycle as with AC, you just magnetize the core almost immediately (and then push it into saturation).


According to my lacking knowledge, a huge current draw at startup is exclusive to electric motors, where the lack of back EMF at zero speed causes big current draw.

This phenomenon is not exclusive to electric motors. All magnetic components will exhibit this effect to a certain degree. This has to do with the loading presented to the magnetic down stream. The power inductor won't do this at all if it has no load on it or is very lightly loaded. At startup, there is either a discharged capacitor that will be almost a short circuit, hence the large inrush current. Or another load that has large startup current until a steady-state is reached.
The video shows a 120MW substation that's serving 100's to 1000's of motors, compressors, industrial machinery, that all have large inrush currents until these machines get up to speed. Then, at that point, the current is substantially reduced to a point where you get that ubiquitous "transformer hum".

okay, the noise being due to the transformer being loaded by all the motors makes total sense. but why would the same noise happen in an inductive heating application, where a coil is loaded by a stationary ferromagnetic part? I could share a drawing or a diagram by editing the original question.

@ÖmerGezer Yeah. Your going to have to clarify - what your describing sounds like a very specific situation. Are you describing an induction heater that does this at startup with out a ferrous core? Or, everything is fine, and then this happens when you stick iron in the furnace AFTER the device is powered up? Do you know if your heater is operating fixed or variable frequency?

I have added drawing and some more details to the question. The coil without the cylinder around it makes a very subtle "hum". When it's switched on with the cylinder mounted it displays the mentioned behaviour. I haven't tried putting the cylinder on after energizing the coil. Heater is run at fized 50Hz frequency.
